# What's the meaning of "beyond the high-level detail" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

When I read this doc [designs](https://github.com/node-red/designs):

> Through consensus, the design can moved to the in-progress state. This is for designs that are actively being worked on beyond the high-level detail.

what's the meaning of "beyond the high-level detail" in this sentence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the *performance* specification (the high level detail) has been worked out, but the low level detail – how that is actually achieved – has not.

In other words, they have decided *what* the design must do, but not *how* it should be done. This is the usual sequence of events. First, a certain need is identified, and then exactly what that need is, and then how to make it happen. Sometimes, it's the other way round: someone invents a new process or object, and then they look around for ways in which it can be used.